# equations of the lines of tangents to the curve at the pole (when r = 0)

Tags: calculus

So the $r$ is given by $r = 1 + 2\sin θ$ and its asking me to find the equations for the lines tangent to the curve at the pole ($r = 0$).
I tried doing $dx = (r)' (\cos θ) + (r) (\cos θ)'$ which gave me the result $(2\cos θ)(\cos θ) - (1+2\sin θ) (\sin θ)$ and so on for the $dy$. but What I have trouble is what do I do after I get the equation in form of $dy/dx$?

Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you differentiate function by $\theta$? You should remind $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x=r\cos\theta \\ dx=dr\cos\theta-r\sin\theta d\theta \\ y=r\sin\theta \\ dy =dr\sin\theta+r\cos\theta d\theta  \\ \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{r'\sin\theta+r\cos\theta}{r'\cos\theta-r\sin\theta}$$

At $r=0$, $r'=2\cos\theta$ $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\tan\theta$$

We need to solve for $\theta$ at $r=0$. This give $$\theta=\sin^{-1}(-\frac12)=\frac{4\pi}{3}, \frac{5\pi}{3}$$